# Refrescar forma sin cerrarla y volverla a abrir

Tags: delphi

Tengo una forma la cual tengo como objetivo que traiga el ultimo dato que se ha insertado en la tabla a la cual esta conectado el Query.

Esto ya lo hace con otro proceso, pero cuando termina la inserción de datos, no logro refrescar ahí mismo sin cerrar nada para que se vea en pantalla el ultimo dato que logró traer la consulta

Digamos que tengo este dato `DESC-01` y yo inserto otro (esto ya se hace con otro proceso) llamado `DESC-02`, yo quiero que cuando termine el proceso de inserción, haga como un efecto como si presionaras F5 en el navegador pero en este caso te trae el ultimo insertado en la tabla

En Google hay varios ejemplos que usan `DataSet.ApplyUpdates()`, `Refresh()`, `Update()` pero no lo consigo, también que si desactivo y activo de nuevo el Query, hace este efecto y se actualiza la info

```
DataModule.MyQry.Active := false;
DataModule.MyQry.Active := true;
```

A lo mejor ya existe esta pregunta que trae como respuesta activando y desactivando el query pero mi duda es, como refresco la forma? tendría que refrescar todos los controles? solo forma actual?

EDIT:

Estoy trabajando con SQL Server 2012 y los componentes de conexión son los `TADOQuery` y `TwwDataSource`

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero es que no comentas con qué Base de Datos (SGBD) estás trabajando, ni con qué componentes de conexión, cosa que es importante para conocer qué está pasando y cual es la posible solución, ya que no todas se comportan igual.

Tienes un **proceso_A** que inserta datos en una tabla (**tablaA**) y un **proceso_B** que lee el último elemento insertado.

Se me ocurren 2 formas de atacar el problema del refresco:

1. Utilizando un **TTimer** de forma que hagas un refresco periódico. Cada x segundos el **proceso_B** lanza una consulta para conocer el último elemento insertado en la **tablaA**. A efectos prácticos, si la consulta está bien diseñada, debaría bastar con hacer un:

   query.Close;
   query.Open;

Para que se volviera a conocer el último valor.

Esto tiene la ventaja de la sencillez y la desventaja de que es un proceso poco "afinado" (demasiado simplón). Puede hacer mejoras sobre esta misma idea para intentar optimizarlo; Jugar con el Timer, activarlo y desactivarlo cuando no se use, variar el tiempo de consulta en función de las inserciones, etc,...

2. Otra opción puede ser utilizando **"Event Notifications"** o **"Eventos de la BD"** si es que tu SGBD y los componentes lo permiten. En este caso puedes configurar que la propia Base de Datos, te avise cuando se produzca una inserción en la **tablaA**, de forma que en ese momento puedes lazar el **proceso_B** que realiza la consulta (para obtener los datos actualizados).

Esto tiene la ventaja de que es mucho más eficiente, consume menos recursos, pero la desventaja de que es más complejo y no todos los componentes y SGBDs lo permiten.

Aquí tienes un artículo sobre este tema utilizando Delphi, por si quieres leer un poco más:
https://neftali.clubdelphi.com/eventos-con-sql-server-y-firedac-query-notifications/

Comment: Buena sugerencia pero en mi caso no me funcionaria esto, lo que hice es generar otro `TADOQuery` llamado MaxRow donde saco el `Max(Id)` de la tabla donde se insertaron los datos, y en la forma donde quiero que haga el refresh pongo

`DataModule.MaxRow.Active:= false;`
`DataModule.MaxRow.Active:= true;`

`DataModule.MyQry.Active := false;`
`//Maximo es el alias de la consulta de MaxRow`
`DataModule.MyQry.Parameters[0].Value:= DataModule.MaxRow.FieldByName('Maximo').AsInteger`
`DataModule.MyQry.Active := true;`

Y listo funcionó a la perfección